# php parsing xml attributes

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I know that is sea of answers and examples about reading attributes from xml files using php. But after trying to implement this, I haven't succeed and therefore I'm asking this.

I have an xml file with the following structure:

```
<warning warning_type="warned">
   <sentdate>20110823</sentdate>
   <senttime>2154</senttime>
</warning>
```

So I would like to know the warning type, for that I'm trying to implement the following php code, but I haven't succeed yet. So any suggestions will be highly appreciated:

```
 $xml=simplexml_load_file('http://myserver.com/ews/VVKRGN_xml');
    print_r($xml);
    $xml_string = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    foreach($xml_string->item->warning as $warning) {
        $warning_type = $warning['warning_type'];
        echo $warning_type;
    }
```

Comment: is `<warning>` the first node in your XML file? XML file needs to have a root node and then children beneath that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `<warning>` node is at the root level of your XML file, then you can simply do:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file('http://myserver.com/ews/VVKRGN_xml');
$warning_type = $xml['warning_type'];
```